# PHP Strtotime returns 1

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
$te='2011-12-07-14-19-30';
$tt=strtotime($te);
echo $te;
echo $tt;
```

It's not outputting the ingteger of the time as expected...

Any ideas?

Comment: likely it does not understand the format.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/dw6gw) in PHP 5.2.11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$te='2011-12-07 14:19:30'; //y-m-d h:i:s format
$tt=strtotime($te);
echo $te;
```

Comment: Tried this, worked, thanks.  For anyone reading this, other replies give links to more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

That is not a [valid compound date/time format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) that `strtotime` will accept. Modify it appropriately before passing it to the function.

One possible and minimal edit would be to remove all dashes and add a "T" between the date and time part.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is not a [valid time string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), it is just numbers separated by dashes.
It might be returning `-1` instead of `1` as `-1` is the default fail response.

Answer (score 0):

Try "2011-12-07 14:19:30" or "2011-12-07T14:19:30Z" (to be iso8601 compliant).

Answer (score 0):

```
$te='2011-12-07-14-19-30';
$arr = explode('-',$te);
$timestamp = mktime($arr[3], $arr[4], $arr[5], $arr[1], $arr[2], $arr[0]);
```

I think it should work :)

Comment: Why the downvote? If he is unable to change the format of the time/date, this will produce a correct timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

It returns FALSE, as the date you pass has invalid format.
From [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise. Previous to PHP
>   5.1.0, this function would return -1 on failure.